# c language, When decimal digit of %g in printf equal to 0.5, and length is more than 6, it is not upper ceil, why?

Tags: c, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, gcc, printf

Here is my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%g\n", 100000.5);
    printf("%g\n", 100001.5);
    printf("%g\n", 100002.5);
    printf("%g\n", 100003.5);
    printf("%g\n", 100004.5);
    printf("%g\n", 100005.5);
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting this output using **gcc**:

```
100000  
100002  
100002  
100004   
100004  
100006
```

In VS2019, I get different output which looks more consistent:

```
100001  
100002  
100003  
100004   
100005  
100006
```

Why does the output differ? Is it about compiler?

Comment: Try another format to see all the possible decimals. Then you will likely see a difference in values that leads to the different rounding.

Comment: Oh and I suggest you look at the generated assembly from the two compilers, to see if the compiler itself does any rounding or uses different values.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it about compiler?

Yes, IEEE 754 defines four possible rounding modes, quoted from the [gcc man pages](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Rounding.html):

> Round to nearest. This is the default mode. It should be used unless
> there is a specific need for one of the others. In this mode results
> are rounded to the nearest representable value. If the result is
> midway between two representable values, the even representable is
> chosen. Even here means the lowest-order bit is zero. This rounding
> mode prevents statistical bias and guarantees numeric stability:
> round-off errors in a lengthy calculation will remain smaller than
> half of FLT_EPSILON.
>
> Round toward plus Infinity. All results are rounded to the smallest
> representable value which is greater than the result.
>
> Round toward minus Infinity. All results are rounded to the largest
> representable value which is less than the result.
>
> Round toward zero. All results are rounded to the largest
> representable value whose magnitude is less than that of the result.
> In other words, if the result is negative it is rounded up; if it is
> positive, it is rounded down.

Therefore gcc uses "Round to nearest" while Visual Studio uses "Round toward plus Infinity"

The good news is that you can change the mode:

> fenv.h defines constants which you can use to refer to the various
> rounding modes. Each one will be defined if and only if the FPU
> supports the corresponding rounding mode.

In your case:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fenv.h>
                                                                                                                                             
int main(void)
{
    fesetround(FE_UPWARD);
    printf("%g\n", 100000.5);
    printf("%g\n", 100001.5);
    printf("%g\n", 100002.5);
    printf("%g\n", 100003.5);
    printf("%g\n", 100004.5);
    printf("%g\n", 100005.5);
    return 0;
}
```